# PowerShell export multiple objects as csv

Tags: powershell, csv, object

I have two columns of data the first is a string array the second is actually an object.  I am looking for a simple way of exporting this as a csv.  I have a version with a foreach loop that builds each string up but it seams like over kill.   I have been trying to use select and select object to get it out somehow.    Note I am just a beginner at powershell so I may be missing something.

My first attempt:

```
$data | Select-Object -ExpandProperty reports  | Select -ExpandProperty data | Select -ExpandProperty rows |  Format-Table $_.dimensions
```

Results in:

```
dimensions                                    metrics              
----------                                    -------      
{New Visitor, "Mozilla}                       {@{values=System.Object[]}}
```

My second one went as far as looping

```
foreach ($report in $data.reports) {
    "Rows:" + $report.data.rows.Count

    foreach ($row in $report.data.rows) {
        $output = ""
        foreach($dim in $row.dimensions) {
            $output += $dim + $seporator
            }

        foreach($met in $row.metrics) {            
            foreach($v in $met.values) {            
            $output += $v + $seporator
            }
        }

        #| Out-File -Append C:\Users\linda_l\Documents\debug.txt
    $output 
    }
}
```

There is a potential for a lot of data here so I would really like to avoid the string building solution.

Note: Data comes from the Google Analytics reporting api

```
$data = Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType 'application/json' -Uri "https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet?access_token=$($token.access_token)" -Method POST -Body $analyticsRequest
```

> reports : {@{columnHeader=; data=}}

From comment:

```
$data | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\linda_l\Documents\debug2.csv"
```

> System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject 
>  reports
>  System.Object[]

Optimal output csv

> New Visitor,S40 Ovi Browser,1,2
>   New Visitor,Safari,3,4

Note its up on [Github](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/eb95ed53c7ae18273434ff6b4789dc7d) steps for getting a [refreshtoken](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/55115de5e8b366be3969b24884f30a39)

Data is coming from the [Google analytics reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#Report)

Comment: Did you get a chance to try Export-Csv ? Something like.. $data | | Export-Csv -Path "C:\.....\*.csv"

Comment: How are you looking to have the object display in the second column? a set of key/value pairs?  multiple columns?  can you show an example of what you'd like the output to look like?

Comment: There you go no dice nice idea though that would have been eazy.

Comment: The data returned is JSON is it not? ConvertFrom-JSON help here? Before the export. You might need to create calculated properties to get the values in a format compatible with CSV

Comment: @MikeGaruccio just normal csv really  metrics has .value

Comment: @matt ConvertFrom-JSON : Invalid JSON primitive:

Comment: Can you show us what `$data` looks like _before_ the pipeline? It should have a good string representation.

Comment: @matt the data is returned from the api in JSON but invoke-restmethod should turn it into a normal PowerShell object.  All you should need to do here is take the second part that is returned as an object, add the string to the object as a property, and then sort and export the object.  Trying to locate a sample of the google analytics return right now(altho if @DalmTo could show the results of just calling `$data` in the console that would help a lot)

Comment: just data by itself is reports : {@{columnHeader=; data=}}   The api response is weird its an array of reports each report contains header and data data then contains rows rows contains dimensions and metrics.  Its confusing any sample would help I am happy to piece together I have run out of ideas to google :)

Comment: ok so it's literally a string followed by an object huh?  that's definitely a bit odd for powershell to parse, is it possible to get just the object w/o the `reports: `?(I'd test myself but I don't have access to my google analytics account while at work and I'm guessing you obfuscated your access tokens in that Gist since I get 401's when running it)  if something like $data.metrics returns a valid object we can start with there and just stuff in any other data that's needed, but need to figure out how to get to just that object first

Comment: lets move this discussion over to [This Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131065/powershell-googleanalytics)

Comment: Sorry I just left work won't have pc access for a while

Comment: no worries, have notifications active, post back whenever you get a chance and I'll take a look if I can